# How to reuse a MVC partial view from Module A in Module B in Orchard Modules?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, module, orchardcms

I want to reuse a partial view from Module A by writing

```
@Html.Partial("~/Modules/ModuleA/Views/Shared/TaskBox")
```

in a view from Module B but the view is not found.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes it's perfectly possible, I think you might have to add the .cshtml extension to the end `@Html.Partial("~/Modules/ModuleA/Views/Shared/TaskBox.cshtml")`

Comment: @Coulton Jeez, right. I think i just gave up to early in searching a solution for this. Why would the view engine need the extension here? Normally it does not find the view when the extension is added...

Comment: Indeed, it's perculiar.. I'm not sure exactly why.  I think it's because it's no longer using the convention that it uses to search for the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible.  When you're providing a full path to  I think you might have to add the .cshtml extension to the end:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Modules/ModuleA/Views/Shared/TaskBox.cshtml")
```

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. This is not the Orchard way... First, you are hard-coding the path to the view. Second, you are not using shapes, and letting them resolve the path to the template to use to render them. Third, you are creating a hard dependency between two modules, that would be easily avoided. In other words, the right answer is: don't. Use shapes instead.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Yeah shapes, i literally avoided the whole shape thing until now as i don't really like the dynamic object / parameter thing. The hard coded dependency is not an issue as both modules are dependent on each other anyway. I will watch the "Understanding shape" upload on youtube, perhaps Sebastien can convince me to use shapes.

Comment: If you are not convinced, let me convinced you, please. And if you watch the video from Amsterdam, then I show how to use shapes with strongly typed models.

Comment: Shapes are awesome, and one of the best parts of Orchard. They are atoms of view models, and the way the templates are resolved is what enables lots of great scenarios, such as alternates, theming, overrides, etc. It would be a real shame to pass on them.